# Custom and sortable column in Flask-Admin

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm using Flask-Admin and SQLAlchemy and struggle to create a custom, sortable field in the listview. I a User and a Photo model like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    photos = db.relationship('Photo', backref='user', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class Photo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'photos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(128))
    publish = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
```

I then create a custom View (UserView), create a custom field called 'test' and use a column_formatters to rewrite it to include the count of photos. While the result is correct, the field isn't sortable. Is there another way to solve this?

```
class UserView(sqla.ModelView):

    column_list = ('username', 'test')

    def _count_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        return model.photos.count()

    column_formatters = {
        'test': _count_formatter
    }

    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy's [Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) which are useful for defining high level functions acting on a model class.

The modified model:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy import select, func

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    photos = db.relationship('Photo', backref='user', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_photos(self):
        return self.photos.count()

    @number_of_photos.expression
    def number_of_photos(cls):
        return select([func.count(Photo.id)]).where(Photo.user_id == cls.id).label('number_of_photos')
```

We've just added the new hybrid attribute. We can access it like a normal table column on a `User` instance: `user.number_of_photos`.

And the modified `UserView`:

```
class UserView(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('username', 'number_of_photos')
    column_sortable_list = ['username', 'number_of_photos']

    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated
```

Here we have to define explicitly the list of sortable/visible columns.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the difference between "@hybrid_property" and "@number_of_photos.expression". Care to elaborate on that? Apart from that it works exactly as it should, but "number_of_members" should be renamed to "number_of_photos".

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks (I tested it in my local app with an actual `ModelView`). 
As far I understand the documentation the `@number_of_photos.expression` part defines how the Python code in `number_of_photos(self)` method translates to the actual SQL expression.